# How to display html content on button click instead of creating new tab like wizard using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I go to my html page on clicking of button from my third tab ? My requirement is that I need to display my testing.html content in the third tab only instead of creating new tab after button click(like: multi-step form wizard, it can have `previous/next` options too). Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/fuqg6a71/2/) is:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can have `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to change the html in the tab based on a flag `$scope.testing`

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xcpd9fqm/

---

EDIT: final fiddle for 3 views in the same tab http://jsfiddle.net/eqc3Latm/

Comment: Hi Gaafar, Thanks for your reply, yes it is working fine as per my requirement, but I have one query that If I add one more button in my testing.html, then if I click it then it should hide previous one and show my latest content. it is not happening like above, as it is coming with existing content, modified as per your fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/xcpd9fqm/1/ . Please let me know.

Comment: just add `$scope.testing = false;` in `test1` function to hide the testing div, here http://jsfiddle.net/amyxpLsr/

Comment: But I can able to see the previous <div> content still even after clicking Test1 button, old content is not hiding.

Comment: You need to handle 3 cases now, I used a variable `tab3` that defines which view to show, here http://jsfiddle.net/eqc3Latm/

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot @Gaafar for your help, it resolved my issue.